# How to load function on previously activity call?

Tags: android

In my MainActivity class:

```
notification=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
countertext=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
notification.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity .this,Main_Screen_Hearingfull.class);
startActivity(i);
}
});
```

in my Main_Screen_Hearingfull class we using

```
    ArrayList<Hearing> contact_array_from_db = db.Get_HearingCaseall(curDate);
    for (int i = 0; i < contact_array_from_db.size(); i++) {
    int tidno = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getID();
    String dateofhearing = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getDateofHearing();
    String remarks = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getHearingRemarks();
    String dateofnexthearing = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getDateofnexthearing();
    Hearing cnt = new Hearing();
    cnt.setID(tidno);
    cnt.setDateofHearing(dateofhearing);
    cnt.setHearingRemarks(remarks);
    cnt.setDateofnexthearing(dateofnexthearing);
    contact_data.add(cnt);
}
    int counter = contact_array_from_db.size();
```

After that I got size of value store in database. Actually I want to use value of counter in MainActivity class means countertext. I
want to set `countertext.setText(counter)` on load page - means in mainactivity started size wil be set on this text `field(countertext)`.

I am using like this on Main_Screen_Hearingfull class

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Main_Screen_Hearingfull.this, MAinActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("counter", counter);
```

and in mainactivity class

```
 COUNTERNEW = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("counter"));
 countertext.setText(""+COUNTERNEW );
```

I want to automatically value loaded on main activity start, but `COUNTERNEW` didnt work. How to set `COUNTERNEW`? I want to set that size use on mainactivity class on countertext, but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `counter` value in `Main_Screen_Hearingfull` is `int` and you are trying to retrieve it using `getStringExtra` in `MainActivity` so replace in `MainActivity`

```
Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("counter"))
```

with

```
getIntent().getIntExtra("counter", 0)
```

Also if you are starting a new `MainActivity` then you will get the `Intent` on `onCreate` or else if you are starting the same `Activity` then you will need to get it on `onNewIntent`

Comment: suppose i get value of counter is 2.when MAinActivity start den dis counter value set on countertext..but intially value of countertext get 0 after dat go in Main_Screen_Hearingfull den we get get 2...but i want to set dis counter value on load..main activity page on call...how do it??plz help me

Comment: You are getting the value of `counter` on `Main_Screen_Hearingfull` but you want to set `2` on load of `MainActivity`(which is before `Main_Screen_Hearingfull`)?

Comment: value of counter get in Main_Screen_Hearingfull class..but want to use on MAinActivity  class..MAinActivity click den go in Main_Screen_Hearingfull dis class and come back to MAinActivity den get value of counter but actually i want intially set dis value we wll get on Main_Screen_Hearingfull...

Comment: yes right...want to set value of counter before Main_Screen_Hearingfull

Comment: that's not possible. How do you set the value about which you know nothing?

Comment: actuallu i m using dis for pending works count and den store on counter and den want to show in front page...

Comment: Then you can pass the data in `Intent` to `MainActivity` once you are done with `Main_Screen_Hearingfull`. Isn't that working for you?

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(Main_Screen_Hearingfull.this, MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra("counter", counter); pass counter value throgh dis...bt Main_Screen_Hearingfull dis class call after MainActivity ...so intially it get 0 den return back to MainActivity we get value of counter like 2 bt want to set previously instead of getting 0...

Comment: How can you set previously when you don't know what the value will be?Or do you want to save the value so that you can use it again once app is closed and opened again so that you can see it `2` in `MainActivity`?